# Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled} with Objective C Xcode 9.3 iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using `UIImagePickerController` to get image from device. I've implemented the following steps:

1. Permission is taken:
   Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description - info.plist
2. Instance of UIImagePickerController is created and presented. Delegate is assigned to self. Camera or Library options are given with UIAlertController.

   ```
   -(void) openGallery {
       UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
       picker.delegate = self;
       picker.allowsEditing = YES;

       UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

       [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
       }]];

       [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Camera" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
           // take photo button tapped.
           picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
           [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
       }]];

       [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Photo Library" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
           // PhotoLibrary
           picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
           [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
       }]];

       [self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
   ```
3. On delegate, image has arrived but, when I tried to upload it to server after converting it into base64, the AFNetworking threw error:

   > Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}
   >   with Objective C Xcode 9.3 iOS 11

   ```
   #pragma mark- UIImagePicker Delegate

   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{
       UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

       [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

       [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
       [self uploadThemeServiceCall: chosenImage];
   }
   ```

I tried creating OS_ACTIVITY_MODE to disable in environment variable, but it didn't work. I tried other solutions available but still it din't work. It was working fine but now it's not.

Answer (score 1):

A:) Make sure object chosenImage is not nil.
B:) Use `NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageObject , 1)` to convert `chosenImage` into `NSData` . Use this imageData as ur `NSUrlRequest` body.

Alse show your code for Function  `uploadThemeServiceCall` here.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. The image is not nil.

Comment: Did u use NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageObject , 1) to get image in nsdata ?

Comment: Here is how you make a post request in AFNetworking 3.0 -

Comment: AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"user[height]": height,
                         @"user[weight]": weight};
[manager POST:@"https://example.com/myobject" parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

Comment: for me, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is not even called. Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Have you set Delegate with your ViewController? @MohamedLee